# How to omit generic parameters during object creation in C#?

Tags: java, c#, generics

In `Java`, I can do that:

```
class JavaClass<A, B>{
    A first;
    B second;
}
```

And then declare an array, a list, or a single object of that type, without supplying generic parameters. They're being automatically converted to `Object`'s, like in an example below:

```
JavaClass someArray = new JavaClass[4];
```

Now, the type of `someArray[0].first` is `Object`.

In `C#`, it doesn't seem to work:

```
class Leaderboard<UserType, UIEntry> 
    where UserType : User
    where UIEntry : UserUIEntry{}
```

And the declaration:

`Leaderboard someLeaderboard = new Leaderboard();`

Gives:

> Using the generic type Leaderboard requires two type arguments.

Is there any equivalent to make this work and allow me to declare that?

Comment: Interesting concept... I don't think c# have anything like that.

Comment: Please see: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: Java fakes generics via type erasure - C# has real generics, where `Foo<X>` and `Foo<Y>` are real distinct types, so: no

Comment: Since arrays are covariant an retained, while generics are invariant and erased, the mixture of both arrays and generics is a recipe for trouble. You can take a look at [OpenJDK's `ArrayList` implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) for a possible solution.

Comment: This doesn't really address your question (like @Turing85 does), but one thing you can do to reduce typing for a generic class like `public class MyClass<T>` when T is expected to be a big long type name is to create a non-generic static factory class with a create method.  `public static class MyClass { public static MyClass<T> Create(T forSomeT) {} }`.  This isn't always appropriate, but it's sometimes much easer to type `var myObj = MyClass.Create(someObject)`than it is to type `var myObj = new MyClass<ReallyLongGenericTypeNameWithMulitpleTypeParameters> ();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, generics in C# and Java are very different, both conceptually and implementation-wise. C# has so-called [reified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)) generics, while Java uses [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). Therefore, looking for similarities between these two languages in generics is usually not a good idea.

In C#, `Leaderboard` and `Leaderboard<UserType, UIEntry>` are two distinct types. If you really want to, you can write

`class Leaderboard<UserType, UIEntry> 
    where UserType : User
    where UIEntry : UserUIEntry{}
class Leaderboard : Leaderboard<User, UserUIEntry>{}`

and then use just `new Leadeboard()` (relying on inheritance). However, I wouldn’t think this is an especially great idea, trading a few keystrokes for worse readability.

Look how e.g. [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple.create?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Tuple_Create__2___0___1_) does it: `Tuple` is a nongeneric helper for the generic `Tuple<...>` class, containing a static `.Create` function which helps with type inference, reducing the need to write the generic parameters explicitly.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the answer. The only problem with that solution is that I still can't store that type in a single container, like `List<Leaderboard>` - which was the main issue here.